# Small Caps does not Work for Section

Tags: titlesec, small-caps, sectsty

I'm writing using  `\article` class and I want to make every section of it centered and small caps with no bold. I use `sectsty`package for this.

I tried it this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,sectsty, blindtext}

\title{\scshape This Is The Title\\\large and this is another text}
\author{Azlif}
\date{Somewhere in 2018}
\sectionfont{\centering \scshape\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstrak}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This paper only contains blind text
\end{abstract}
\section{I Hope I can Be a Small Caps Someday}
\blind text
\section{Other Section}
\section{Yet Another Section}
\end{document}
```

I also try adding 
`\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}`. It works but then the section heading is not centered.

Comment: If you stare long enough at `\scshape\normalfont` perhaps you can find the solution your self. Hint: what does `\normalfont` do? Hint2: try changing the order. Also probably a good idea to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Oh gosh. It works perfectly. I should've just put that `\normalfont` at the front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a fairly simple human error. `\normalfont` resets the font settings, so `\scshape\normalfont` is the same as just `\normalfont`.

Try `\normalfont\scshape`.

Answer (score 1):

With `titlesec`, just add to your preamble

```
\titleformat*{\filcenter\scshape}
```